# Annotate each result with a value indicating if minimum or maximum of field

Tags: python, django, database, query-optimization

I have two models, `Author` and `Book`:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)

class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    publication_date = models.DateField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, related_name="books")
```

Now when I get a set of authors and their books, I want to annotate each book with two values indicating if it is the cheapest or most expensive out of the filtered books from the same author.

I got the correct results using `Exists` and annotations

```
filtered_books = Book.objects.filter(publication_date__year=2010)

lower_price = filtered_books.only('id').filter(price__lt=OuterRef('price'), author=OuterRef('author'))
higher_price = filtered_books.only('id').filter(price__gt=OuterRef('price'), author=OuterRef('author'))

filtered_books = filtered_books.annotate(
    lowest_price=~Exists(lower_price),
    highest_price=~Exists(higher_price),
)

authors = Author.objects.annotate.prefetch_related(Prefetch('books', queryset=filtered_books))
```

It works but results in three (`lower_price`, `higher_price` and the prefetch) very similar subqueries being executed and is not that fast. How can I optimize it?

Comment: Why not ordering by price and getting the .first() and .last() items?

Comment: How would I do that? I can't think of a way where I don't need to run a subquery for each annotation.

Comment: Yeah, doing like this will hit the db 2 extra times for each book list which is not good. Maybe you can work on some raw sql to do this with only one query, or you can retrieve the list and doing the annotation process on memory. I guess you don't want the list to be ordered by price as default right?

Comment: I would like to avoid doing raw SQL since I need this to work with multiple database backends. I'm not even sure what it would look in raw sql either. Doing the annotation in memory won't work either since I probably will apply some filters on the annotations in the future too.

Comment: Do you know the Q object? It is used for complex queries which may yield with more efficient sql output . I'm also thinking of a Q object query for your scenario but you might also want to check it out.
   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

Comment: Yes, I know about `Q` but I'm not sure how it helps here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now when I get a set of authors and their books, I want to annotate
>   each book with two values indicating if it is the cheapest or most
>   expensive out of the filtered books from the same author.
>
> It works but results in three (lower_price, higher_price and the
>   prefetch) very similar subqueries being executed and is not that fast.
>   How can I optimize it?

- You can't escape from these 3 queries, they will aways be presented
  in one form or another.
- Having 3 similar queries does not mean they are 3 times slower than a single query, this needs more investigation in order to find where the bottleneck is, it could be a missing index or smt else.
- Indicating whether a book is the cheapest or the most expensive means you need to compare the book price with some min/max prices. Once having this min/max prices the comparison is easy. Since you want to do this book comparison against author's other books in the queryset, it makes more sense to this in the Authors queryset. An example:

  ```
  filtered_books = Book.objects.filter(publication_date__year=2010)

  min_price_subquery = (filtered_books
      .filter(author=OuterRef('pk'))
      .values('author')
      .annotate(min_price=Min('price'))
      .only('min_price')
  )

  max_price_subquery = (filtered_books
      .filter(author=OuterRef('pk'))
      .values('author')
      .annotate(max_price=Max('price'))
      .only('max_price')
  )

  authors = Author.objects.annotate(
      min_book_price=Subquery(min_price_subquery, output_field=models.IntegerField()),
      max_book_price=Subquery(max_price_subquery, output_field=models.IntegerField())
  ).prefetch_related(Prefetch('books', queryset=filtered_books))

  for author in authors:
      for book in author.books:
          if book.price == author.min_book_price:
              #cheapest price
          if book.price == author.max_book_price:
              #most expensive
  ```